# Is there an easy way generate a probable list of words from an unspaced sentence in python?

Tags: python, nlp

I have some text:

```
 s="Imageclassificationmethodscan beroughlydividedinto two broad families of approaches:"
```

I'd like to parse this into its individual words. I quickly looked into the enchant and nltk, but didn't see anything that looked immediately useful. If I had time to invest in this, I'd look into writing a dynamic program with enchant's ability to check if a word was english or not. I would have thought there'd be something to do this online, am I wrong?

Comment: You could encode your dictionary of words as a trie and use a greedy algorithm: pull the longest word that matches and then go on to the next word, backtracking on failure. Probably not optimal. Try this for recommendations on data structures: http://kmike.ru/python-data-structures/

Comment: Interesting question. I'd guess the answer ("easy way") is going to be "no".

Comment: Similar question asked before that didn't have much luck: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13034330/how-to-separate-an-engilsh-language-string-without-spaces-to-form-some-meaningfu

Comment: For example, how would your algorithm know that it's not `be roughly divide din to`? They are all correct English words...

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker: Because that is not the greedy approach. "Greed, for lack of a better word, is good. Greed is right. Greed works." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gordon_Gekko#.22Greed_is_Good.22_quotation

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466972/how-to-split-a-string-into-words-ex-stringintowords-string-into-words

Comment: You may refer to this solution

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870261/how-to-split-text-without-spaces-into-list-of-words

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Greedy approach using trie

Try this using [Biopython](https://github.com/biopython/biopython) (`pip install biopython`):

```
from Bio import trie
import string


def get_trie(dictfile='/usr/share/dict/american-english'):
    tr = trie.trie()
    with open(dictfile) as f:
        for line in f:
            word = line.rstrip()
            try:
                word = word.encode(encoding='ascii', errors='ignore')
                tr[word] = len(word)
                assert tr.has_key(word), "Missing %s" % word
            except UnicodeDecodeError:
                pass
    return tr


def get_trie_word(tr, s):
    for end in reversed(range(len(s))):
        word = s[:end + 1]
        if tr.has_key(word): 
            return word, s[end + 1: ]
    return None, s

def main(s):
    tr = get_trie()
    while s:
        word, s = get_trie_word(tr, s)
        print word

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = "Imageclassificationmethodscan beroughlydividedinto two broad families of approaches:"
    s = s.strip(string.punctuation)
    s = s.replace(" ", '')
    s = s.lower()
    main(s)
```

## Results

```
>>> if __name__ == '__main__':
...     s = "Imageclassificationmethodscan beroughlydividedinto two broad families of approaches:"
...     s = s.strip(string.punctuation)
...     s = s.replace(" ", '')
...     s = s.lower()
...     main(s)
... 
image
classification
methods
can
be
roughly
divided
into
two
broad
families
of
approaches
```

## Caveats

There are degenerate cases in English that this will not work for. You need to use backtracking to deal with those, but this should get you started.

## Obligatory test

```
>>> main("expertsexchange")
experts
exchange
```

Comment: Wonderful. This is just what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

This is sort of a problem that occurs often in Asian NLP. If you have a dictionary, then you can use this http://code.google.com/p/mini-segmenter/ (Disclaimer: i wrote it, hope you don't mind).

Note that the search space might be extremely large because the number of characters in alphabetic English is surely longer than syllabic chinese/japanese.