# Technical Word Separation

Tags: dataset, nlp, data-mining

For a project I require a database of technical computer science words (to be more specific the words belonging to academic nature, so stack overflow tags might not work in general). I am trying to build the database using Coursera lecture text files, but the problem with them is because of "ASR" the text is not clearly separated from each other, for example 'severaltransitions' occur together in one of the text file. Is their anyway by which I can separate them out? Also any help would be appreciated if there is any existing similar database.

Answer (score 2):

The following post is very similar to yours and can give you some insight. The essential idea is to create an isword() method and try it on all splits of strings that are not dictionary words. isword() can be optimized by using a trie. This approach is pretty straightforward and should be fast enough if you only attempt to split words that fail a spell check.

[How to split a string into words. Ex: "stringintowords" -> "String Into Words"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466972/how-to-split-a-string-into-words-ex-stringintowords-string-into-words)