# Word Segmentation without Spaces in Swift

Tags: swift, tokenize, nltokenizer

I have disabled users who typically are writing without a space. I want to help with this and do word segmentation in a SwiftUI app. I can't find a natty library to do this, so I figured I would use the NaturalLanguage API to give it a try. I feel this doesn't work because of a lack of spaces.. oh the irony

```
import NaturalLanguage

func insertSpaces(in continuousText: String) -> String {
    let tokenizer = NLTokenizer(unit: .word)
    tokenizer.string = continuousText

    var spacedText = ""
    tokenizer.enumerateTokens(in: continuousText.startIndex..<continuousText.endIndex) { range, _ in
        spacedText += continuousText[range] + " "
        return true
    }

    return spacedText.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
}
```

And running it, eg.

```
let spacedSentence = insertSpaces(in: 'HELLOMYFRIENDS')
```

Doesnt work. Am I right that this is impossible and I need to build my own dict to look at boundaries?

Comment: Tokenizer is not the right tool, you might be able to add spaces with OpenAI.

Comment: What do you want to do when it is ambiguous? For example "therapist". This is never going to work 100%. What do you mean "*writing* without a space"? Do they use a handwriting keyboard? I think, to really solve this problem, you'd need to consider other aspects of the disability, instead of just fixing the symptom of "no spaces". What exactly is the disability here?

Comment: @sweeper - conisder dragging your finger through a board of letters to spell a message eg. "IWANTADRINK". They are used to doing this for years and a human intepreting the word boundaries. Yep - it doesnt always work with a human either.

Comment: @Sweeper see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SDkE-aO3tOQ for an idea.. we can do a swift app to detect spelling by dragging but occasionally users like the one shown really have a hard time adding spacing

Comment: Apple's tools don't do this (the built-in autocorrector can do some of it, but we don't have sufficient access to make that work IMO, and it's not powerful enough for this, also IMO). You will need to build it yourself. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466972/how-to-split-a-string-into-words-ex-stringintowords-string-into-words for some advice.  Best of luck; this is definitely a worthy problem. I suggest reaching out to Apple. They may be willing to help (probably by baking it into the keyboard; not by giving us an API).